# Iframe closing without refreshing the main page that contains the iframe

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

I am using an iframe in a page where the iframe looks like a div on the main asp.net page. In the Iframe page i have got a close button and when i click on close button i am calling a javascript function in iframe page which is having the code as:

window.location.href = "Pagename.aspx";

this line closes the Iframe but the main page which contains Iframe refreshes after closing the iframe so.... I tried in many ways to close the iframe without refres like

window.close();

but it is not working. The main problem to close the iframe is that the close btn is in the iframe page it self so if i write the code to close iframe in iframe page that does not work.....

The main issue being that the iframe close btn should work like a div close btn that means when i click the close btn div can be made as dislay none but iframe how can i make it close when the iframe value can be accessed in the main page that contains iframe but that iframe page cannot get the iframe name....

So, can u please help me solve this issue .. that is closing of iframe without refreshing main page that contains iframe. Thanking you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you control the parent page? You could put the script to close the iframe in the parent. So, in the parent page you have

```
function myCloseIframeFunction(){
  /*close iframescript*/
}
```

and then call parent.myCloseIframeFunction() from the iframed page.

Comment: Thank You so much the solution worked.... !!! i am calling as u told the iframe closing function as parent.myCloseIframeFunction()... and it worked! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Actually this worked fine in both Firefox an Chrome but in IE8 when i used this code it worked fine for the first time when i clicked on close button but the second time i clicked to open the iframe the iframe did not open... and it showed an error first one for opening frame in IE console as:LOG: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains. Can u please help thank U in advance!!

Comment: can I get a link? It sounds like its a crossdomain error because the domain for the iframe doesn't match the domain of the iframe which is only a problem for communicating across domains.

Answer (score 0):

Write the following Javascript function in the `Page which is being called in Iframe`..Call this function on Close button Client Click Event...

```
      function close()
       {
                var ifr = parent.document.getElementById(IframeId);
                ifr.parentNode.removeChild(ifr);
       }
```